# Fatal error: abstract class not found in other class

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class, fatal-error

I have an abstract class 'AbstractClassA':

```
abstract class AbstractClassA {
    //some code...
    public static function isValidID($id) { ... }
}
```

And another abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractClassB extends AbstractClassA {
    const id = 1111;
}
```

Then when I declare the following in the third class:

```
class OrdinaryClass {
    public static function canDoIt($id) {
        return AbstractClassB::isValidID($id);
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error when I check the following:

```
OrdinaryClass::canDoIt(1111);
```

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AbstractClassB' not found in OrdinaryClass.class.php on line ##"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: Are they in one file or in different? If in different, do you load your classes somehow?

Comment: @Justinas they are in different files. No, I don't load them somehow. I just call 'OrdinaryClass' from php view. Without AbstractClassB it works fine, but if I use it in return statement in canDoIt() function, then fatal error happens.

Comment: You should look into PSR-4 Autoloading and maybe use composer as it does a very good job automatically generating classmaps and autoloaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having files in different files, you must `require` them first before using:

```
<?php

require_once "/path/to/AbstractClassA.php";
require_once "/path/to/AbstractClassB.php";

class OrdinaryClass {
    public static function canDoIt($id) {
        return AbstractClassB::isValidID($id);
    }
}
```

---

There is option to register [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for this to be done automatically.

```
// autoloader.php

spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    include __DIR__ . '/' . $className . '.php';
});
```

---

```
// OrdinaryClass.php
require 'autoloader.php';

class OrdinaryClass {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I used `require_once`. The problem was that I didn't include the first abstract class.